# Eclipse unable to run Spark java project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I have maven spark java project which I want to run on my local pc, but getting some scala related error.

Please see below console output. Not sure what exactly is wrong here.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.spark.craft.demo.SparkApplication).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 209
Exception Details:
  Location:
    scala/collection/immutable/HashMap$HashTrieMap.split()Lscala/collection/immutable/Seq; @249: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:58)
    at com.spark.craft.demo.SparkApplication.start(SparkApplication.java:34)
    at com.spark.craft.demo.Application.main(Application.java:51)
```

Comment: Show us yuor pom.xml. It seens you Spark dependency is pointed wrong

Comment: Hi Bruno, I was using latest spark-core library but when I changed to old spark-core library it worked.